# awk: Join lines based on beginning or ending pattern

Tags: awk

I have a multiline file where the records are separated by a new line `(\n)`.

Each record split is identified by some text `break`.

How can I use awk so that if the record begins or ends with `break` it joins it onto the previous or next line, whilst retaining the record separator.

Input (`$` represents EOL). Multiple `breaks;` can be ignored or treated as one:

```
A| break;$
B| break;$
C| break;$
D$
E|$
break; FGH|$
break; IJ| break;$
KLM| break;
NOP$
```

Desired output:

```
A|B|C|D$
E|FGH|IJ|KLM|NOP$
```

Current code (works on end `break;` but no join the lines beggining with `break` onto the previous one:

```
awk '{if (sub(/break;$/,"")) printf "%s", $0; else if (sub(/^break;/,"")) printf $0,"%s"; else print $0}' myfile
```

I suspect the problem is in the else if part but I cant figure out the correct syntax to join onto the previous line if the line begins with `break;`.

Any help would be appreciated but please consider `awk` solutions only.

UPDATE:

Thank you everyone who contributed! The suggestions below work, but it seems some records with consecutive `break;` in them are still causing problems:

```
A| break;
B| break;
C| break; break;
break; D$
```

Comment: With Perl: `perl -0777 -pe 's/ break;\n//g; s/\nbreak; //g' file`

Comment: If you're feeling ruby: `cat file | ruby -ne 'print $_.gsub(/ *break; */,"").sub("|\n","|")'`

Comment: Including `$` in your sample input/output to represent end of line isn't useful since we can already see where your lines end. It just makes it so we have to edit your sample to remove the `$`s before we can test with it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk '!/break;|\|$/{print s $0; s=""; next} {gsub(/ *break; */, ""); s = s $0}' file

A|B|C|D
E|FGH|IJ|KLM|NOP
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/ ?break; ?/,""); printf "%s%s", $0, (/\|/ ? "" : ORS)}' file
A|B|C|D
E|FGH|IJ|KLM|NOP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/break;|\|$/ {line =line $0;gsub(/ *break; */,"",line);next}{$0 = line $0;print $0;line=""}' file
A|B|C|D
E|FGH|IJ|KLM|NOP
```